# Comment tagging is flaky

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Half the time, I type the @ symbol and it doesn't pop up anybody. Also, when I tag somebody and it doesn't autosuggest the user, The tag gets stripped out of the comment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the @ to tag the name of the person who posted the question or answer it will be stripped out automatically as it is unnecessary.  They will be notified anyway.

Once you start typing a name after the @ sign  autocomplete depends on how long ago that user was there, I think. Certainly just typing @ shouldn't suggest a name until you start typing it.

Comment: Ohhh you're right. I was trying to tag the person who provided the answer.